# Java Decimal Format - as much precision as given

Tags: java, parsing, format, decimal

I'm working with `DecimalFormat`, I want to be able to read and write decimals with as much precision as given (I'm converting to `BigDecimal`).

Essentially, I want a `DecimalFormat` which enforces the following pattern "\d+(\.\d+)?" i.e. "at least one digit then, optionally, a decimal separator followed by at least one digit".

I'm struggling to be able to implement this using `DecimalFormat`, I've tried several patterns but they seem to enforced fixed number of digits.

I'm open to alternative ways of achieving this too.

Edit:

For a little more background, I'm parsing user-supplied data in which decimals could be formatted in any way, and possibly not in the locale format. I'm hoping to let them supply a decimal format string which I can use the parse the data.

Answer (score 6):

Since you noted in a comment that you need Locale support:

```
Locale locale = //get this from somewhere else
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(new DecimalFormatSymbols(locale));
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
df.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
df.setParseBigDecimal(true);
```

And then parse.

Comment: Interestingly, when I tried parsing an invalid number calling `df.toLocalizedPattern()` caused a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: a) that's odd. Might be a bug? b) why would you want to create a localized pattern. Wouldn't you just parse using the format instance directly?

Comment: Only for error reporting, it's passed to the constructor of an exception.

Comment: This was much appreciated. Had a problem with EditText in android formated my double (removed the E numbering) so I had to reformat it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("0.#");
    f.setParseBigDecimal(true);
    f.setDecimalFormatSymbols(new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US));// if required


    System.out.println(f.parse("1.0"));   // 1.0
    System.out.println(f.parse("1"));     // 1
    System.out.println(f.parse("1.1"));   // 1.1
    System.out.println(f.parse("1.123")); // 1.123
    System.out.println(f.parse("1."));    // 1
    System.out.println(f.parse(".01"));   // 0.01
}
```

Except for the last two that violate your "at least one digit" requirement. You may have to check that separately using a regex if it's really important.

Comment: I do, however, run into a problem when trying to write out a decimal number - `f.format(3.14) // 3.1`, ideally this would output `3.14` too - is there any way to do so?

Comment: hmm, just make the pattern longer (e.g. `new DecimalFormat("0.##")`) according to the precision you need. In your case, you can also use the default DecimalFormat constructor.