# Java. double convert to string

Tags: java

First of all, thanks for help!
I have some value of fraction and i have to take a decimal part and to convert it to String value,
for example:
double d = 0.005;  i need to put in the String value "005" 
here i used next code:

```
    Double d = 0.005;
    String str = String.valueOf(d);
```

but i don't know what to do here

```
Double d = 0.0000006;
```

the result of

```
String str = String.valueOf(d);
```

is "6.0E-7" but i need "0000006". Can anybody help me?

Thanks God! I've found a decision, guys! Thanks to all!

```
import java.math.*;

public class str7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        Double x = 0.00000000023;

        BigDecimal bigDec = new BigDecimal("1");
        bigDec = BigDecimal.valueOf(x).multiply((bigDec));
        bigDec = bigDec.stripTrailingZeros();
        String dec = bigDec.toPlainString();
        System.out.println(dec+"     "+dec.length());   

    }       
}
```

The result is a string "0.00000000023", that's what i need :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class to format doubles. Beyond that I think you're just a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465019/java-decimal-format-as-much-precision-as-given).

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = Double.toString(d);
```

http://ideone.com/7jZU2u

Comment: Thanks! But if d = 0.000003 the result of this code will be "3.0E-6" and i need a string with "0.000003"